# html in email from Django

Tags: django

I'd like to know whether or not I can include anchor tags in the 'txt_message' that I send from django. Will they be displayed as hyperlinks within the email that the user sees?

My understanding is that the txt_message is only rendered when the email server won't accept the html_message. I want to ensure that the user sees and can click on the hyperlink that I send them (regardless of whether I they are seeing the txt_message or the html_message.

```
    send_mail(subject,
       txt_message,
       from_email,
       to_email,            
       html_message=html_message,
       fail_silently=False)
```

Thanks for the help!

Comment: What does it look like if you send yourself an email?

Comment: silly question, but I assume what will show up in the console will represent the txt_message. Is that right?

Comment: I'm not sure, but it seems like you can find the answer to this question by sending an email to yourself and seeing how it looks

Comment: It has nothing to do with the receiving server, but the client to display the message. You can't change the behaviour of user's mail client. If it converts text links into clickable links, great. If it doesn't, it's a pity.